# How do I hide the function parameters in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, nginx

How can I hide the parameters in Codeigniter?

I have this URL:

```
http://example.com/profile/1
```

I want to hide the '/1' in the URL but I'm struggling here. I want to hide it because the 1 in the URL is the user id. So I want it to be hidden from public view

I am using Nginx. I tried rewriting it by using

```
location ~^ profile {
     rewrite ^profile/ http://example.com/profile? permanent
}
```

but this isn't working, it just kept on redirecting and redirecting

I tried changing it but it isn't working.. Please help me out

Comment: Just curious, but how are you planning to find which user's profile it is without passing in their ID from somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. How do you let the server know which profile to look for if the URL doesn't provide the parameter?

Comment: thanks, i thought it was possible because many sites have beautiful URLs without parameters..

Comment: @KevinLee: Which site would be an example?

Comment: Rather than hiding the user_id, why not pass the username (if there is one) in the URL instead?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the ID by POST instead of GET and then the URL will not contain an ID

Comment: Yes. This is done in Wordpress too - you have the provision to remove the ID all together. Its simply the GET and POST that you have to play with.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to hide user_id from public. At least no secuirty risk at least. If you want to hide your user id there is another way to make hash function and use it instead of database id